# How to use controls for creating static variables

Tags: dynamic, gui-construction

I try to create a static variable initialized by some control.
Let's create `PopupMenu` control

```
SomeText = "SomeText";
PopupMenu[Dynamic[PS], {0 -> "Prefix", 1 -> "Suffix"}]
```

Then, on the base of the control, a variable `StringForLater` is initialized

```
StringForLater = Dynamic[If[PS == 0, StringJoin["Prefix", SomeText], StringJoin[SomeText, "Suffix"]]]
```

Later `StringForLater`performs as a dynamical variable, but I need another behavior: after selecting an item in `PopupMenu` make `StringForLater` static, not dynamic.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this is what you want.  You can use the tracking function argument to `Dynamic[]`:

```
SomeText = "SomeText"; (* I avoid starting vars with caps; so someText *)
PopupMenu[
 Dynamic[PS,
  (PS = #;
    StringForLater =   (* Ditto: stringForLater instead of StringForLater *)
     If[PS == 0, StringJoin["Prefix", SomeText], 
      StringJoin[SomeText, "Suffix"]]
    ) &],
 {0 -> "Prefix", 1 -> "Suffix"}]

Dynamic@StringForLater
```

(Avoiding initial capitals means my symbols won't conflict with built-in symbols.)

Comment: Thank you. Indeed, It works as needed. I'm surprised that Mathematica needs some tricks in order to implement simple things :((